# Embedding Cmx.io code in LaTex?

Tags: graphics, programming, markup

This may seem a bit silly, but here goes.

There's a project called [Cmx.io](http://cmx.io/) that allows you to create xkcd-style comics using an HTML markup. I wanted to include comics like these in a book I am writing with LaTeX. Since I have 0 artistic skills but a lot of HTML savv, I thought about using this. But is there any way that I can embed/put in any way this kind of thing in LaTeX?

Comment: Can you download a png or jpeg? Otherwise, I think it will be quite complicated...

Comment: @darthbith Nope to my knowledge.